# Encrypted string From Delphi to C#

Tags: c#, delphi, aes, encryption

i am trying to decrypt one string in c# encrypted in Delphi with Cipher1  3.0,  Part I from Delphi Encryption Compendium.
I use TCipher_Rijndael.

string that i encrypt is : this-is-a-test-example

password: pass

encrypted values is : iKBC8kX4ZEk4A1pCj6jwEegqjpxhqw==

When i try to decrypt this in c# i recive error: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Did anyone have the same problem, and what is a solution?

Here is a decrypt method in c#:

```
public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherData,
                                byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();  
        Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();      
        alg.Key = Key;
        alg.IV = IV;
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
            alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);           
        cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length);    
        cs.Close();
        byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

and here is encrypt code in Delphi:

```
with TCipher_Rijndael.Create('pass',  nil) do
      begin
        memo2.lines.add ( CodeString( 'this-is-a-test-example' , paEncode, fmtDEFAULT));
        Free;
      end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: This smells of encoding issues - how are you converting to string in both applications?

Comment: Are you decoding the string into a byte array before attempting to decrypt it? The encrypted string you entered is encoded with Base64 encoding -- the two equals signs at the end are a giveaway. So first you'll have to convert them to a byte array using Convert.FromBase64String.

Comment: Of course i convert string to byte array.

Comment: What is the encrypted result if C# encrypts it? and can C# decrypt its encrypted string?

Comment: Yes, a already answer, when i encrypt in c#, i can decryipt in c#.

Comment: @buda: The question here is, the c# encryption result is the same as Delphi result? how it is different?  Answering this will help you and maybe us to find where's the problem.

Comment: The problem may be ASCII/ANSI vs. Unicode.  Because as I understand it, the encryption/decryption is based on bytes not characters.  So I would expect problems if the Delphi is 2007 or earlier and the C# is Unicode.

Comment: @jachguate C# encryption result is NOT same as Delphi encryption result.

Comment: @buda, the important question here is why they are different? Check important aspects of the encryption process: The memory representation of the string is the obvious one; in D2009 or later, a string var is a WideString (2bytes/char). Other input to the crypt function like the key is also WideString, some algorithms see this as a sequence of bytes not chars, so this is very important.  Other internal details of the "choices" or paths of the particular encryption you choose have to be the same in both, Delphi and C#.  You'll gain enough understanding with this proc. to make the decrypt work.

Comment: @buda: Edit your question and post the C# encrypted string so we can compare.

Answer (score 5):

You need to determine all of the details of how that value was encrypted:

1. What [block cipher mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) was used? ECB tends to be a default.
2. What [padding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) was used? Perhaps no padding in your case.
3. How was the [key derived](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) from the password? Perhaps with [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or simply a [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash.
4. What was the [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)? Note that only some cipher modes require one.
5. How was the output encoded? It appears to be [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding for you.

Only once you know exactly how it was encrypted can you reverse the process to properly decrypt it. You might want to try posting more code or details about how it was encrypted. Then someone might be able to determine how you need to go about decrypting it. I've seen [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398125/what-cipher-mode-padding-defaults-or-common-uses-of-aes-encryption-would-be-used) with unknowns before and I managed to guess the details to find the answer. I tried a few common ways with your encrypted string, but I can't easily decrypt it without more details.

Answer (score 3):

You are saying that you can encrypt in C# and decrypt in C#. You can also encrypt in C# and decrypt in Delphi. This means that your C# encryption is definitely fine. That leaves just one possible culprit: Delphi encryption.

So do this:

- Encrypt in C#.
- Encrypt in Delphi.
- Compare the outputs.

They can't possibly be the same. See in what way they differ. Is one Base64-encoded and the other just raw bytes? Is one padded with == and the other not? Do they use different Base64 variants?

Comment: If you also post both "encrypt" outputs here we'll have a better chance of helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Try going the other way.  i.e. encrypt the string in c# and see if it matches.  See if your C# solution can even eat its own dogfood.

Comment: Everything is OK when i encrypt string in c# and decrypt in c#, it all works.

Comment: So how long is the encrypted string from c#?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Delphi encryption encodes the string as an Ansi string (one byte per character) and the C# encryption encodes the string as a Unicode UTF16 string (two bytes per character). If you are using Delphi 2007 and below this is almost certainly the case.

PS The length of the encrypted string in Delphi is also a bit of a giveaway - 32 characters for a 22 character raw string implies one byte per character - this is not the case for C#.

Comment: Make sure that the string encoding used by Delphi is UTF16 (the same as C#), or use Ansi encoding specifically in C#.