# Delphi C# Communication encryption

Tags: c#, delphi, encryption, integration, communication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encrypted string From Delphi to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690438/encrypted-string-from-delphi-to-c)

I have one question,

what is the best solution to encrypt communication between two systems, one is developed in Delphi and one is developed in c#. I already tried that and had some problems, all is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690438/encrypted-string-from-delphi-to-c) but i did`t find solution.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You should answer the questions posed in [the first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690438/encrypted-string-from-delphi-to-c/5690642#5690642) to that other question. If you answer those you'll likely find the problem.

Comment: What exactly did you already try?

Comment: As it stands, this is a "close - exact duplicate" candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa376210.aspx

CNG is supported beginning with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista. As this is WINAPI it should easily work with Delphi, and for .NET there exists wrapper classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163441.aspx

another Option is to create a COM Wrapper for your C# code. (maybe a bit less secure)

Comment: you could also use Indy... http://www.indyproject.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by using [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) in .net app([old post how to enable ssl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2004/11/10/255467.aspx)), in such way you would get communication based on http protocol.
On top of that you can use additional layers:
a) [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta), lightweight RESTful library
b) [Self hosted WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFSSL.aspx)