# Need Clarification: Encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key

I answered a question some days back and I got a downvote :-). Well, I'm still not able to find out what is wrong in my understanding of public key cryptography.

The question was nice and was:

If a string is encrypted in JAVA and .NET the resulting encrypted string is different but when reaches @ server it can be decrypted correctly.

My answer was:
[RSA Encryption in Java/.NET and decryption in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893321/rsa-encyption-in-java-net-and-decryption-in-net/5893456#5893456)

I would like to understand what was wrong with the answer. Comments?

Comment: You didn't answer the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public key is used to encrypt the message, which the destination decrypts using its Private key.

Your answer was down-voted probably because you stated the reverse.